# "RULE sth OUT ON/OVER people's complaint"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Let's say a government of a country implemented an UNBENDING rule on its citizens that they should pay higher taxes than other countries. You hypothetically say:

> "if the government **rule** the high tax payment **out over** us, citizens here would organize a protest against it.

Or should it be:

- **Rule out** the high tax payment **on** us

There is a *fixed phrase* for this and correct preposition to express is *grammatically* and to not sound awkward.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me. "Rule out" has a specific meaning of "exclude", but that does not seem to fit your context. Is there a particular reason you want to include the word "out"?

Comment: Also, "rule" as a verb can mean "govern" (as a king rules a kingdom) or "issue a ruling" (as a judge gives a decision). Which definition are you intending here?

Comment: Sounds like John Arvin may be thinking of "roll out" (implement), and also thinking (mistakenly) that a government can be said to "roll out" something over the populace like e.g. a steam roller is rolled over tarmac or a cook's rolling pin is rolled over pastry, that is impose it in a dictatorial fashion. Nice image, John but we don't use 'roll out' that way. Maybe you could use 'impose"? e.g. ""if the government imposes the high tax payment on us, citizens here would organize a protest against it."

Comment: To 'rule out' something is to exclude it from a set of choices.

Comment: If our government rules in favor of such a high tax, the citizens here would organize protests against it.

Comment: That's it! "impose". It was on the tip of my tongue, but not anymore. Thx you guys.